# Get all the cities of a state

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to list all the cities of a state.

Here an example of my table "**properties**"

```
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+
| id | title       |price   | state  | city          |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+
| 1  | test        | 55     | Florida| Jacksonville  |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+
| 2  | test 2      | 30     | Nevada | Las Vegas     |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+
| 3  | test 3      | 200    | Florida| Miami         |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+
```

**index.blage.php** template:

```
    @foreach($all_cities as $city)
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <a href="{{url('listing?keywords=' . $city->city )}}">  {{$city->city}}</a>
    </div>

    @endforeach
```

**HomeController.php**

```
   public function home()
    {

        $all_cities = Property::select("city")->groupBy('city')->get();
        return view('index', ['all_cities' => $all_cities]);

    }
```

For example get all cities of Florida.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
$cities = Property::select("city")
                        ->whereState('Florida')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I have a small issue,  Let say in my properties table I have 3 houses in Florida , city Miami  it will list Miami 3 times in the listing but it should list Miami only 1 once. How can I list Miami only once ?

Comment: You can add `->groupBy('city')` after `whereState` !

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick

`$all_cities = Property::select("city")->where("state","=","Florida")->get();`